# How to create an instance of a "dynamic(decided at runtime)" class?

Tags: java, generics

I have several classes, say MyClassA MyClassB MyClassC and MyClassD

I want a function that given the Class type would create (and do whatever..) an object which is an instance of the class.

So my function would look like this,

```
public void foo(ClassType MyChoosenClassType){
       MyChoosenClassType x=new MyChoosenClassType();
       //do whatever with x
}
```

Is there a way I could do this?

Or will I have to do everything manually with if conditions and my own ways ?

Comment: Do these classes share a common interface?

Comment: no, but they are extended from the same class, say MyClassParent

Comment: What's the constructor of these classes?

Comment: Anyway, here is how you can create instances: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the Java Reflection API, by using the [`Class.getConstructor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) and [`Constructor.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) methods:

```
public <T extends MyClassParent> void foo(Class<T> classType) throws Exception {
    T instance = (T) classType.getConstructor().newInstance(); // no-args constructor assumed

    // work with instance, which is a subclass of MyClassParent
}
```

This works, as long as all subclasses of `MyClassParent` have a no-args constructor. If they all had another constructor, you could pass the class of the expected arguments to `Class.getConstructor()`, and the actual argument values to `Constructor.newInstance()`. Please refer to the docs for further details.

However, with Java 8, you could avoid using reflection:

```
Map<String, Supplier<? extends MyClassParent>> facotries = new HashMap<>();

factories.put("MyChosenClassType1", MyChosenClassType1::new);
factories.put("MyChosenClassType2", MyChosenClassType2::new);
// etc
```

Then, you could implement your `foo` method as follows:

```
public void foo(String classType) {
    Supplier<? extends MyClassParent> factory = factories.get(classType);
    if (factory != null) {
        MyClassParent instance = factory.get();

        // work with instance
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do the factory thing (and avoid reflection) in earlier versions of Java too; it's just not as succinct without the `::new` lambda expression.

Comment: I still wonder if there is a way that is so elegant and straightforward as in my example code of question. Cannot this be done using <T> or gererics?

Comment: is reflection that bad?

Comment: @SadeepDarshana No, it's not that bad, especially in Java8 it has been highly improved.

Comment: @Wyzard Agreed, you can use anonymous inner classes in Java7. But that makes the code look so ugly...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do what I exactly mentioned in the question; However this is the solution I finally came up with. Not so easy and straightforward as I mentioned in the example code in the question.
As Jimmy T. mentioned

```
public void foo(Object anyObjectOfTypeMyClass){
       Object x=anyObjectOfTypeMyClass.getClass().newInstance();
       //do anything with x
}
```